# What are the dimensions, file types, and ppi resolution of an iOS app icon?

Tags: iphone, ios, icons

What are the specifications for the icons required by Apple for a custom iPhone application published?

> 57x57, PNG, No Transparency, No Layers, 72 PPI
>
> 512x512, TIFF or JPEG, No Transparency, No Layers, 72 PPI

Note: iPhone OS applies rounded corners, optionally shine, and other effects

Also have a large version of your logo with the name of the application in case Apple contacts you needing a version for marketing purposes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The icon should be a 57x57 pixel PNG. The PNGs generated by Apple have a PPI of 72.01 so I guess something in that range will work fine. Don't have a very high PPI else images are not rendered properly.

If you want to use a custom icon and not let the iPhone to apply the gloss to your icon, add a key to info.plist called UIPrerenderedIcon (is a boolean value) and make it checked.

When submitting the app to the app store, you will need a 512x512 pixel version of your app's icon (this one in jpeg or tiff format) and at least one screenshot of your app. You can have additional 4 screenshots of the app.

**EDIT**
Now the specs for icon (to be submitted in iTunes connect) and the app icons have changed. The icon to be submitted to itunesconnect must be 1024x1024 px.

For the app icons, you can find details here - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1

Also, make sure the icon files are NON-INTERLACED PNG files. Recently one of our apps' binary was marked invalid since one of the app icon files was an interlaced PNG.

Comment: PPI doesn't matter, only the dimensions.

Comment: My app icon for iPhone 4 is 114x114 Pixels, 72 DPI and named Icon@2x.png, But it's not taking up the full space for the icon, anyone know whats going on?

Comment: **Update**: Now apple recommends the icon file in 1024 X 1024 dimensions. You can have more info at [documentations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html).

Answer (score 13):

From [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/chapter_14_section_2.html):

To ensure that your icon can take advantage of these visual enhancements, provide an image in PNG format that:

- Measures 57 x 57 pixels, with 90 degree corners (if the image measures other than this size, iPhone OS scales it)
- Does not have any shine or gloss

Name your icon file Icon.png and place it at the top level of your application bundle.

Comment: What are the specifications of the icon to be submitted for the iTunes store? Are the requirements for that icon published?

Comment: Updated link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Answer (score 6):

As of May 2012, the official Apple Docs include this chart:
[image]

This describes the icons that must be visible in the app. The docs also say the file must be jpeg or png but doesnt specify a dpi.

You must also include a larger copy for the page in iTunes. Again, from the apple docs

[image]

[full docs available here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html)

Answer (score 4):

The new retina display is at 114 x 114 for icons.

Answer (score 2):

To submit app to iTunes store you need to have following sizes:

- 57x57
- 72x72
- 114x114
- 228x228
- 512x512

Reference: http://ios-funda.blogspot.in/2013/02/all-icon-size-needed-for-app-store.html

Answer (score 1):

The app store is looking for a 512x512 icon as well (not sure the PPI).  Best bet is just to design it as vector then you can easily resize and export it as whatever.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://mrgan.tumblr.com/post/708404794/ios-app-icon-sizes) describes all icon sizes and where are they used.

Answer (score 0):

57x57 pixels png... you can choose via code to apply or not the gloss effect.

Answer (score 0):

I made a complete list of the ten (10) needed app icon files in my blog post, [iOS App Icons, Listed and Summarized](http://crafted-software.blogspot.com/2013/06/ios-app-icons-listed-and-summarized.html) . My information is current as of iOS 3, 4, 5, and 6. Two links take you to the crucial Apple documentation.

I show three tables, each listing the icon files needed for:

- Handheld devices (iPhone, iPod touch)
- Tablet devices (iPad)
- iTunes & App Store

Answer (score 0):

> Note: iOS ignores the PPI (Pixels Per Inch) of icon images. You may
>   author your icon images at any PPI but their width and height, as
>   measured in pixels, must match the values in the tables below.

This is coming from [Apple Technical Q&A QA1686](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html) and contains also information about sizes and files types.