# Custom Finder (folder) Image w/ Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, finder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Using Cocoa to create an icon for a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739330/using-cocoa-to-create-an-icon-for-a-folder)

I'm trying to set a **custom folder image**, but only with **cocoa**, as dropbox:
[image: Dropbox custom folder image]

 But I realized that this isn't really simple.

Anyone with some solution/tip?

Answer (score 1):

Use `- (BOOL)setIcon:(NSImage *)image forFile:(NSString *)fullPath options:(NSWorkspaceIconCreationOptions)options` method of [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Class.