# Set icon of a Mac folder

Tags: macos, packagemaker

I am making an installer with packagemaker for Mac OS X, and i would like to have my bundle placed inside a directory together with another executable for uninstallation. The problem that I have is that i would like to have that directory to have customised icon. So can anyone tell me what is the best way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems not like a programming related question.
By the way:

1. Select the volume, application, folder, or file whose icon you want
   to stamp onto another, just click the icon to select it.
2. From the File menu, choose Get Info or press Command-I to open the
   Info window.
3. Click the icon in the upper-left corner of the Info window to select
   it.
4. From the Edit menu, choose Copy or press Command-C.
5. Select the volume, application, folder, or file whose icon you want
   to replace.
6. From the File menu, choose Get Info or press Command-I.
7. Click the icon in the upper-left corner.
8. From the Edit menu, choose Paste or press Command-V to replace the
   icon.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739330/using-cocoa-to-create-an-icon-for-a-folder) is how to set it programmatically with **cocoa** and **obj-c**.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can download special apps from appStore...

Or do it:

1. Click the volume, application, folder, or file whose icon you want to paste onto another item.
2. From the File menu, choose Get Info or press Command-I to open the Get Info window.
3. Click the icon in the upper-left corner of the Get Info window to select it.
4. From the Edit menu, choose Copy or press Command-C.
5. Select the volume, application, folder, or file whose icon you want to replace.
6. From the File menu, choose Get Info or press Command-I.
7. Click the icon in the upper-left corner.
8. From the Edit menu, choose Paste or press Command-V to replace the icon.