# Large App icon while submitting to app store is blurred

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, app-store, appstore-approval

I am uploading my app to the app store for the first time. I am new at uploading to the app store, too. I noticed that we have to upload a 1024 x 1024 pixels app icon for app store purpose in iTunes Connect. I didn't know about this. I have a 114 x 114 app icon and resized it to 1024 x 1024. After resizing it to this extent it became blurred.

But if I try to upload the same blurred app icon in iTunes Connect, it is accepted and it is looking reasonably good in iTunes Connect. But I don't know how it looks in the app store after submission.

Does Apple reject because of this blurred app icon in iTunes Connect? As the icon is looking good in iTunes Connect, will it look the same in the app store too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can proceed. It will definitely work.

Comment: Thanks suraj. In itunes connect, the app icon is in 180 x 180 size. Even i opened in app store and saw few apps. Their sizes are around 150 x 150. Then why apple is asking for 1024 x 1024?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475410/what-are-the-dimensions-file-types-and-ppi-of-an-iphone-icon.

Comment: it is apple specification.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Although it is strange that the app icons will not be shown anywhere in 1024 x 1024 size but apple needs it..